# Deployment script works differently than expected

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trrying to deploy via GitHub Action. With a push on deployment the test instance should be built and with a PR on the main branch the production instance should be built and deployed.

However, with the current GitHub Actions workflow configuration (`main.yml` and `staging.yml`), a push on deployment triggers both workflows, which is not what I want.

What do I have to change in the workflow to achieve my goal?

**main.yml**

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
    - main
name: Deployment on pull-request to main
jobs:
  web-depoly:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2

    - name: Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
      with:
        server: myside.com
        username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        server-dir: /production.myside.com/
```

**staging.yml**

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - development
name: Deployment on push to deployment
jobs:
  web-depoly:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.2

    - name: Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
      with:
        server: myside.com
        username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        server-dir: /staging.myside.com/
```

Comment: Presumably by _"with a PR on the main branch"_ you mean when the PR is _merged_, in which case that's `push: branches: - main`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes i mean `is merged`. And thank you for comment. i will check it out and give a response here.